# update Parquet file format

Tags: parquet, upsert

my requirement is to read that and generate another set of parquet data into another ADLS folder.

do i need this into spark dataframes and perform upserts ?

Answer (score 1):

Parquet is like any other file format.  You have to overwrite the files to perform insert, updates and deletes.  It does not have ACID properties like a database.

1 - We can use SET properties with the spark dataframe to accomplish what you want.  However, it compares at both the row and column level.  Not as nice as an ANSI SQL.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-setops.html

2 - We can save the data in the target directory as a DELTA file.  Most people are using DELTA since it has ACID properties like a database.  Please see the merge statement.  It allows for updates and inserts.

https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-update.html

Additionally we can soft delete when reversing the match.

The nice thing about a delta file (table) is we can partition by date for a daily file load.  Thus we can use time travel to see what happen yesterday versus today.

https://www.databricks.com/blog/2019/02/04/introducing-delta-time-travel-for-large-scale-data-lakes.html

3 - If you do not care about history and soft deletes, the easiest way to accomplish this task is to archive the old files in the target directory, then copy over the new files from the source directory to the target directory.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed options . Regarding #2 above , my source send me data as parquet , so are you asking me to read the parquet into a spark and then store into my destination in a delta format ?

Comment: That is if you want to have the ability to go back in time (time travel).  Otherwise, just archive old and copy over new.  Regardless, you have to set a time limit on how long to keep data.